# How to decrypt stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which is encrypted using the WITH ENCRYPTION option. Now I want to decrypt that procedure. I have already tried a stored procedure called "Decryptsp2K" which is given for SQL 2000 in this forum: http://forums.asp.net/t/1516587.aspx/1

But it deletes my stored procedure, rather than decrypting it.

Is there a way to decrypt a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The SQL Server Pro article ["Decrypt SQL Server Objects"](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/decrypt-sql-server-objects) still works in SQL Server 2008.

You need to connect via the DAC. See the file "Decrypt SQL 2005 stored procedures, functions, triggers, views.sql" in [the download](http://www.sqlmag.com/content/content/95728/95728.zip).

Just to summarise the steps that it performs for the following stored procedure definition

```
CREATE PROC dbo.myproc
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
SELECT 'FOO'
```

1. Retrieves the encrypted object text from the `imageval` column in `sys.sysobjvalues` and stores it in a variable `@ContentOfEncryptedObject`
2. Calculates `@ObjectDataLength` from `DATALENGTH(@ContentOfEncryptedObject)/2`.
3. Generates an `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement padded out to the correct length with the `-` character (so in this case `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc] WITH ENCRYPTION AS------------`)
4. Executes the `ALTER` statement, retrieves the encrypted version from `sys.sysobjvalues` and stores that in the variable `@ContentOfFakeEncryptedObject` then rolls back the change.
5. Generates a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement padded out to the correct length with the `-` character (so in this case `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc] WITH ENCRYPTION AS-----------`). This gets stored in the variable `@ContentOfFakeObject`

It then loops through for `@i = 1 to @ObjectDataLength` and decrypts the definition a character at a time using the following `XOR` calculation.

```
NCHAR(
      UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@ContentOfEncryptedObject, @i, 1)) ^
      (
          UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@ContentOfFakeObject, @i, 1)) ^
          UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@ContentOfFakeEncryptedObject, @i, 1))
      )
     )
```

> **UPDATE**
>
> Paul White has written a very nice article that goes into details on
>   why the above works, and that gives an alternate method that doesn't
>   rely on altering the object: [The Internals of `WITH ENCRYPTION`](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/05/sql-performance/the-internals-of-with-encryption)

Comment: It seems like this returns all the code but in an incorrect sequence (I'm using SQL2008R2). I have quite a long stored proc and the results need to be put back together as follows: line 9 goes to the end of line 7, line 10 goes to the end of line 8, line 11 goes to the end of line 9, but it is not consistently 2 line that jump, anyone else experiencing problems with this?

Comment: @AdriaanDavel - I didn't come across that myself when looking at the code in the article. I have also used [Optillect SQL Decryptor](http://download.cnet.com/Optillect-SQL-Decryptor/3000-10254_4-75300271.html) which seems to work fine.

Comment: To decrypt SQL Server database stored procedure you can use XOR decryption process as mentioned in this helpful post http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/zoras-sql-tips/2016/02/16/a-guide-for-decrypting-sql-server-database-objects/

Comment: I've always used Orbital's SQL Decryptor which can be found here:
[http://www.sqldecryptor.com](http://www.sqldecryptor.com)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to decrypt procedure or any other encrypted object, check out [ApexSQL Decrypt](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_decrypt.aspx).

It’s a free standalone tool, with an option to integrate it into SSMS, preview original DDL script, and create Alter or Create decryption scripts.

From a standalone tool you can connect to multiple servers and decrypt multiple objects at once.

[dbForge SQL Decryptor](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/) is the other tool that can help you out in this case as well.

Comment: ApexSQL Decrypt did not work for me on a SQL Server 2012 database.

Answer (score 3):

Many older tools stopped working with SQL Server 2005+. Note you must be using the `Dedicated Admin Connection`

A quick search shows several options.

- http://www.sql-shield.com/decrypt-stored-procedure.html

Comment: I think it's all paid versions, not free. I have checked decryptor from http://www.elitude.net/ link.

Comment: @Upendra Chaudhari: probably only paid for apps out there. It all changed with SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 2):

> Decrypt Stored procedure of SQL SERVER

You can use third party tool for decrypting your encrypted stored procedure.

Download that tool-: It's freeware

https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/download.html

Answer (score 1):

***dbForge Sql Decryptor*** helped me to decrypt the encrypted stored procedure.
Details are available [here](https://blog.wsol.com/using-sql-decryptor-to-work-with-encrypted-sql-server-objects)