# how to decrypt an encrypted stored procedure using a query

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
   alter proc spGetNamebyId
   @Id int
   with encryption
   as
   begin
   select Name from tbl_Emp where Id=@Id
   end
```

I have above encrypted stored procedure , which i want to decrypt using query, can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

The Best awy is to decrypt your encrypted stored procedure for free then Refer this link

**[Ckeck Here For Decrypt](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Decrypt-encrypted-stored-procedures)**

There are other solutions also to Decrypt your SP 
Please refer this link also

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662224/how-can-we-view-the-encrypted-stored-procedures-body-in-ssms)

Comment: please tell me if you facing any difficulties @Charan Raj Acharya

Comment: I am not able to decrypt the encrypted stored procedure.@Hardik Parmar.  If u know how to decrypt the above stored proc then please help me here.