# Encrypting and decrypting procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I have a few procedures for my application and I need to deploy the application and all procedures onto the client's SQL Server machine.

I don't want the client to access any code so how can this be done?

I can get a user created for me though which I can create the procedures and tables such that no other user can see it but the `SA` user on the client machine will still be able to see it.

Is there a way I can hide my code?

Comment: In short: **NO** You *can* "encrypt" a stored procedure, but that encryption is very weak, and any power user and admin can reverse it. And there's no way to "hide" your entire code base from an `SA` admin on that server.

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60129/how-to-view-an-encrypted-view-or-stored-procedure

Comment: Why are you specifically wanting to hide your code? More often than not the reason is because of bad coding (e.g. you are hiding sensitive information is something that is insecure)

Comment: see this as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670636/how-to-decrypt-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008/7671944#7671944

Answer (score 2):

If you have some procedures that need to be decrypted, you can check out [ApexSQL Decrypt](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_decrypt.aspx).

You can create Alter or Create decryption scripts, preview of the original DDL script, or to decrypt from SSMS.

Also, you can even decrypt objects located in databases from multiple servers and it’s a free tool.

Other tool that you can check out is [dbForge SQL Decryptor](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/).