# How to remove encryption from all objects in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, dbforge

I have more than a hundred encrypted procedures and functions that I want to decrypt (I am trying a bacpac file export but it fails due to procedures being encrypted). I tried using [dbforge sql decryptor](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/) decryption wizard for in place alter but I get the error:

> Definition is invalid. Can't find CREATE keyword.

When I try to see the DDL script of a stored procedure(using dbforge sql decryptor), I get the error:

> A definition for the object dbo.pt_blocks cannot be shown because it is encrypted by a third party tool

I can not find a resolution to this. Are there any solutions or other tools available for this?

Edit: I found [this resource](https://thomaslarock.com/2013/05/migrate-encrypted-procedures-azure-sql-database/) which mentions

> take the source code and issue an ALTER command without the encryption option. Just take the source code and remove the WITH ENCRYPTION

How could I achieve this?

EDIT: I have enabled remote DAC. How can I decrypt everything? The accepted answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670636/how-to-decrypt-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008) has a broken link.

Edit: The problem has been solved by uninstalling a third party tool which was creating encrypted procedures.

Comment: You will find a number of other tools and scripts that can do this with an internet search. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670636/how-to-decrypt-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008). Note that object encryption is actually only obfuscation.

Comment: If it was trivial to access the unencrypted contents without any kind of administrative access the feature would be of even less use then it arguably already is. Assuming you are an administrator on the machine, you *could* open a DAC connection by, say, enabling `xp_cmdshell` and calling out to `sqlcmd`, or else by scheduling a job that does the same (`sqlcmd -S admin:(local)`). Extremely clunky, especially since you have to write a script that does it all in one go, but it's an option.

Comment: If you can control the firewall of the machine (i.e. you're not merely a sysadmin but also a Windows admin and PowerShell remoting is an option) you can also enable the DAC for remote access (`sp_configure 'remote admin connections'`), which is marginally simpler.

Comment: There is no solution without a DAC connection. Note that remote DAC connections is a configurable option.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I have enabled remote DAC and updated the question.

Comment: There's more than one link in that answer -- [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/05/sql-performance/the-internals-of-with-encryption) basically hands you everything as well.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a PowerShell example that creates a script file of all encrypted objects, gleaned from Paul White's [The Internals of WITH ENCRYPTION](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/05/sql-performance/the-internals-of-with-encryption) article. Change the data source and initial catalog in the 2 connection strings to the desired server and database as well as script file path.

A [DAC connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators) is used to retrieve values from system tables so `sysadmin` server role membership is required. If run remotely, the SQL Server `remote admin connections` option must be enabled and TCP port 1434 allowed through the firewall.

The script can be run from the PowerShell ISE or from a command prompt after customization. Example command-line invocation, assuming script was saved to file "Decrypt-Objects.ps1".

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File C:\PowershellScripts\Decrypt-Objects.ps1
```

PowerShell script:

```
# PowerShell implementation of T-SQL code from https://sqlperformance.com/2016/05/sql-performance/the-internals-of-with-encryption

Function Get-DecryptedString($pwd, $data) {

    $key = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([int], 256)
    $box = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([int], 256)
    $cipher = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([byte], $data.Length)

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 256; ++$i) {
      $key[$i] = $pwd[$i % $pwd.Length]
      $box[$i] = $i
    }

    for ($j = $i = 0; $i -lt 256; ++$i) {
      $j = ($j + $box[$i] + $key[$i]) % 256
      $tmp = $box[$i]
      $box[$i] = $box[$j]
      $box[$j] = $tmp
    }

    for ($a = $j = $i = 0; $i -lt $data.Length; ++$i) {
      ++$a
      $a %= 256
      $j += $box[$a]
      $j %= 256
      $tmp = $box[$a]
      $box[$a] = $box[$j]
      $box[$j] = $tmp
      $k = $box[(($box[$a] + $box[$j]) % 256)]
      $cipher[$i] = ($data[$i] -bxor $k)
    }

    $decryptedString = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($cipher)

    return $decryptedString

}


Function Get-ClearObjectText($connectionString, $objectName) {

$getRc4KeyQuery = @"
DECLARE
    @objectid integer = OBJECT_ID(@ObjectName),
    @family_guid binary(16),
    @objid binary(4),
    @subobjid binary(2);
 
-- Find the database family GUID
SELECT @family_guid = CONVERT(binary(16), DRS.family_guid)
FROM sys.database_recovery_status AS DRS
WHERE DRS.database_id = DB_ID();
 
-- Convert object ID to little-endian binary(4)
SET @objid = CONVERT(binary(4), REVERSE(CONVERT(binary(4), @objectid)));
 
SELECT
    -- Read the encrypted value
    @imageval = SOV.imageval,
    -- Get the subobjid and convert to little-endian binary
    @subobjid = CONVERT(binary(2), REVERSE(CONVERT(binary(2), SOV.subobjid)))
FROM sys.sysobjvalues AS SOV
WHERE 
    SOV.[objid] = @objectid
    AND SOV.valclass = 1;
 
-- Compute the RC4 initialization key
SELECT @RC4key = HASHBYTES('SHA1', @family_guid + @objid + @subobjid);
"@

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($dacConnectionString)
    $connection.Open()
    
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($getRc4KeyQuery, $connection)
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@ObjectName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 261)).Value = $objectName
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@imageval", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarBinary, -1)).Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@RC4key", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Binary, 20)).Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
    [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $imageval = $command.Parameters["@imageval"].Value
    $RC4key = $command.Parameters["@RC4key"].Value
    $connection.Close()

    $decryptedString = Get-DecryptedString -pwd $RC4key -data $imageval

    Return $decryptedString


}

# ############
# ### MAIN ###
# ############

# DAC connection string for decryption
$dacConnectionString = "Data Source=admin:YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI"

# normal connection string for encrypted object list
$connectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI"

# target file path for clear encrypted objects DDL
$scriptFilePath = "C:\Scripts\EncryptedObjects.sql"
[void](New-Item -Path "C:\Scripts\EncryptedObjects.sql" -ItemType file -Force) # create directory (if needed) and empty script file

$EncryptedObjectQuery = @"
SELECT
     QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) AS QualifiedObjectName
FROM sys.objects
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsEncrypted') = 1;
"@

try {

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($EncryptedObjectQuery, $connection)
    $connection.Open()

    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()

    while ($reader.Read()) {

        $createObjectScript = Get-ClearObjectText -connectionString $dacConnectionString -objectName $reader["QualifiedObjectName"]

        $createObjectScript | Out-File -FilePath $scriptFilePath -Append
        "GO" | Out-File -FilePath $scriptFilePath -Append

    }

    $connection.Close()

}
catch {

    throw

}
```

Comment: I am a complete beginner so I apologize for my ignorance. As far as I understand, when I connect using DAC in SSMS I can run this code in new query. From the code I see that I should change 'YourServer' to my server details and 'tempdb' to the database. Could you explain what else I need to change?

Comment: @TheloniousMonk, SSMS can only run T-SQL scripts (technically it can run PowerShell from a PS window but that's too long of a story for a newbie).  I added more info about modifying and executing the script to my answer. Note only one DAC connection is allowed so I suggest you close SSMS if you've previously established a DAC connection.

Comment: I use a username and password to login to the database. Does this mean I also have to change 'Integrated Security=SSPI' to 'User ID=xxx;Password=xxx'? I am wondering how the DAC connection in this script is established (I successfully tested DAC connection using Powershell by using admin: prefix)

Comment: @TheloniousMonk, yes you need to change the connection strings as you mentioned if you want to use SQL authentication instead, although I'm not sure why you would want to do that if Windows authentication works.

Comment: I ran the script, but don't think anything happened. The objects are still encrypted.

Comment: @TheloniousMonk, this script only creates a script file with the original `CREATE` statements. Is your need to actually remove encryption from all the objects?

Comment: Yes, need to remove encryption